# Cannot mount, partition, format brand new USB

Tags: partitioning, usb, gparted

I've recently bought a new TDK 4 GB USB stick, but when I try to mount it (I'm runnning Ubuntu 12.04, but neither in Windows 7/8.1 it works) in various ways Gparted, Disk Utility, simply pluggin it into usb port, I receive this error: `unrecognised disk label`.

Using `sudo parted /dev/sdc` it gives the same error and with GParted I've successfully managed to understand that no partition exists (when attempting to create a new partition it does nothing).

Is it completely broken out, or have I any possibility to rescue this brand new USB?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It sounds like the disk is bogus, but check the output of `dmesg` for any more detailed errors after trying to format it.

Comment: [ 1086.950660] usb 3-3: new high-speed USB device number 5 using xhci_hcd
[ 1086.967193] usb 3-3: New USB device found, idVendor=0718, idProduct=0710
[ 1086.967208] usb 3-3: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[ 1086.967217] usb 3-3: Product: TF10                          
[ 1086.967224] usb 3-3: Manufacturer: TDK LoR                       
[ 1086.967231] usb 3-3: SerialNumber: 1227000000006790
[ 1086.968020] usb-storage 3-3:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
[ 1086.968146] scsi7 : usb-storage 3-3:1.0

Answer (score 1):

Using `gparted`, select your USB disk in the right top drop-down.

**Please be careful, since the next step will remove any data in your USB stick.**

After that, unmount any active partitions and go to `Device > Create Partition Table...`. Then select `msdos` and `Apply`.

Finally, create a new partition using the filesystem you want (usually FAT32) and `Apply All Operations`.

Comment: after selecting "msods" Gparted does nothing! After operation there are no operations pending ...

Comment: "e2label: Bad magic number in super-block while trying to open /dev/sdc
Couldn't find valid filesystem superblock"

Comment: @Foga Can you run `sudo fdisk -l /dev/sdc` and paste the output here?

Comment: Disk /dev/sdc: 4009 MB, 4009754624 bytes
124 heads, 62 sectors/track, 1018 cylinders, total 7831552 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0xe4991204

Disk /dev/sdc doesn't contain a valid partition table

Comment: @Foga Open the `gnome-disks` (it is native in Ubuntu), select your USB device on left list, click on the gear icon on right top, then `Format`. Erase: Quick / Partitioning: MBR/DOS. After finish, it will display `Free Space` in `Volumes`. Click in the plus (+) icon, change type to FAT and click over `Create`.

Comment: but there's no gear icon! And eventually, I tried format with a different button and it gives this error: "Daemon is inhibited"

Comment: @Foga Well, you could try to create the partition table on command line. `sudo fdisk /dev/sdc`. On `Command (m for help):`, type `o` and press enter. After that, type `w` and press enter again. To finish, `q` to quit `fdisk`. Then run `sudo fdisk -l /dev/sdc` and see if the `Disk /dev/sdc doesn't contain a valid partition table` error still happening. If do not, you can open any graphical partition editor and create your partitions.

Comment: First, when opening fdisk itt gives out "Warning: invalid flag 0x0000 of partition table 4 will be corrected by w(rite)", and when running last command to see if a partition table was created it gives out: "Disk /dev/sdc doesn't contain a valid partition table"

Comment: Even after that warning, was you able to run the `o` and after the `w` on `fdisk`?

Comment: of course, but no way .. still "Disk /dev/sdc doesn't contain a valid partition table"

Answer (score 0):

Reading all the information above, I must conclude that your brand new USB stick is DOA (Dead on Arrival).  Return it to the store and get a replacement.  Print out this page as proof that even the über-geeks at Ask Ubuntu cannot get it to work and it is our informed opinion it's DOA.

*Sorry to be the harbinger of bad news*

Comment: Don't thank me!  ;-) If you like my answer, just click the little grey **☑** under the "0" now turning it into beautiful green.  If you do not like my answer, click on the little grey down-arrow below the 0, and if you *really* like my answer, click on the little grey checkmark *and* the little up-arrow...  If you have any further questions, go to http://askubuntu.com/questions/ask